# Find $Var(S^2)$ when $S^2 = \sum_{ i=1}^ n (x_i - \bar{x})^2$.

Tags: statistics

I know that the expectation of $S^2$ is $\sigma^2$, but I am having trouble finding the expectation of $(S^2)^2$

Comment: The expectation of $S^2$ is not $\sigma^2$ but $(n-1)\sigma^2$ according to your definition.

Comment: oh my mistake, I meant to put 1/(n-1) in front of the sum, because S^2 is an unbiased estimator